# Elections and running mass data.stackexchange queries?

Tags: discussion

One of the Stack Exchange sites is going through the election process. I wish to avoid my personal opinion when I decide, basing my decision on data instead.

Is there any way to run the relevant *data.stackexchange.com/SUBSITE/queries* against a specified bunch of users (that is, all the users putting themselves up for election)?

It'd be awesome if the output was a pretty [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) graph too.

Perhaps the community has come up with a set of queries useful for this situation?

(Tagged as `discussion` because maybe this is a horrible idea.)

Comment: I would have suggested [this site](http://se.awio.com/election.html) but it appears not to have been updated recently.

Comment: @ChrisF I prodded Yi Jiang about it, and we're working on fixing that.

Comment: @Tim - thanks for the info. I don't feel so bad about suggesting the page elsewhere before I checked and found it wasn't updated.

Comment: @Tim - I feel a bit guilty that my question has caused someone to get a prod.  Please ensure a VERY GENTLE prod, perhaps with a nice soft plushy, or some tasty food item?

Comment: It's okay, we poke and prod people all the time! http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=poke+stick&room=89